# Android Marshmallow permissions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am working on an application which requires

```
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
```

so I was wondering if rather than asking user to individually accept these permissions if I can ask user to accept the permission group instead. In this case it is the storage group. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) You need to ask both the permissions at the time you need them and not together. If you ask for one permission the system will ask permission for the whole group the permission belongs. If user grants the permission you will get permission to whole group.

> The dialog box shown by the system describes the permission group your app needs access to; it does not list the specific permission. For example, if you request the READ_CONTACTS permission, the system dialog box just says your app needs access to the device's contacts. The user only needs to grant permission once for each permission group. If your app requests any other permissions in that group (that are listed in your app manifest), the system automatically grants them. When you request the permission, the system calls your onRequestPermissionsResult() callback method and passes PERMISSION_GRANTED, the same way it would if the user had explicitly granted your request through the system dialog box.
>
> > Note: Your app still needs to explicitly request every permission it needs, even if the user has already granted another permission in the same group. In addition, the grouping of permissions into groups may change in future Android releases. Your code should not rely on the assumption that particular permissions are or are not in the same group.
>
> For example, suppose you list both READ_CONTACTS and WRITE_CONTACTS in your app manifest. If you request READ_CONTACTS and the user grants the permission, and you then request WRITE_CONTACTS, the system immediately grants you that permission without interacting with the user.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense, the tutorial I was following did not covered this part thoroughly.